# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors,Error: tools:replace specified , but no new value specified app main manifest

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-manifest

I am getting Manifest merger failed with multiple errors while adding firebase dependencies

I tried adding `tools:replace` tag, that is what is adding to the errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ecommerce"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label,name">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

no

Comment: could you add the error log ?

Comment: thanks, i solved this issue by migrating to androidX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace, the Android Studio build system also migrates those dependencies for you when you set the following two flags to true in your **gradle.properties** file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

For more [Click here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate)